# Problem regarding Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-center, shutter

A day back everything was fine when using the Software Center. The problem started after attempting to install the app named 'Shutter' (app for taking screenshots) yeasterday. I started the Install then went to watch a movie came back to my PC 3hrs later it was showing 'Applying Changes' it was odd as the software was just 15MB and should have got over. Later on... after 2 hours of staring 'Applying Changes' I couldn't wait no more and  had to shutdown the PC. Today morning when I opened the Software Center the 'Applying Changes' was still there, I cannot install any other software using the center as it says 'waiting' for the Shutter App to finish and I want to stop the installing but just can't as there is no X or Cancel button to stop it.
Using the Terminal I've tried >>

```
mohd_arafat_hossain@TUD:~$ sudo killall -9 apt-get
[sudo] password for mohd_arafat_hossain: 
apt-get: no process found
mohd_arafat_hossain@TUD:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
mohd_arafat_hossain@TUD:~$
```

What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: AAAHHHHHH!! How could I have forgotten this!!! -.-. Thanks jasmines

Answer (score 0):

user@ChrUbuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. user@ChrUbuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up virtualbox-kernel-mods-3.4.0 (1.0-1) ...
 - Starting VirtualBox kernel modules